# Expression interpolation Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I need a help with Angular 8. My code is now like this:

`this.starClicked.emit(' The rating ' + this.rating +  ' was clicked');`

But I tried to put like this and didn't work:

`this.starClicked.emit(' The rating ${this.rating} was clicked');`

My result is exactly the same string: 
`The rating ${this.rating} was clicked`. 
I don't know how I put this Expression interpolation to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick `` ` ``.